# Insert row with $wpdb when clicking on link via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I cannot seem to get this code to work, I'm trying to insert a row into a WordPress database on the click of a button.

### header.php

```
if( isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['user_id'], $_POST['post_id'] ) ) {

global $wpdb;

$datetime = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );

wpdb::insert(
    ‘wp_favorites’,
        array(
            ‘user_id’ => $_POST['user_id'],
            ‘post_id’ => $_POST['post_id'],
            ‘datetime’ => $datetime
        )
    );
    die();
}
```

### template.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '.favorite' ).click( function() {
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>",
            data: { "action": "add", "post_id": "<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>", "user_id": "<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>" }
        } ).done( function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        } );
    });
</script>


<a class="button favorite"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons 3.0/svg/white-heart.svg" width="18" height="18" /></a>
```

### //ERROR

[image]

Comment: so uhm, whats the question all about?

Comment: Updated, I cannot seem to get this code to work.

Comment: You need to provide the error message you're getting.

Comment: Updated with error

Comment: Do you have checked that you could make a AJAX call correctly? Try first echo exit to verify that AJAX call is correct.

Comment: That error wont help much. Only tells that it's a server error. You need to check the PHP error log (or maybe it's being echoed in the AJAX response).

Comment: How do I get the ajax error response?

Comment: @BradFletcher try echoing some message if you can make a call, because WP has some different way to call AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code (However, it's not standard practice but for you) try following code.

**template.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.favorite').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
            data: { "action": "add_data", "post_id": "<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>", "user_id": "<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>" },
            beforeSend: function() {
                // If you want to add loader code
            }
            success: function(response) {
                if( response == 'inserted' ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                }
                // If you have loaded remove that here.
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add following code (copy and Paste as your code has backquote which would not be accepted in array ) into your 
**active theme's functions.php file**

```
add_action("wp_ajax_add_data", "add_data");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_add_data", "add_data");
function add_data() {

}
if($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['post_id'])) {

    global $wpdb;

    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_favorites',
        array(
            'user_id => $_POST['user_id'],
            'post_id => $_POST['post_id'],
            'datetime => $datetime
        )
    );

    if( $wpdb->insert_id ) {
        echo 'inserted';
    } 
    die();
}
```

Remove all your code mentioned in question.
It should work for you!